# Using angular-in-memory-web-api with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

I'm running into some frustrating issues while attempting to add [`angular-in-memory-web-api`](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) to my Angular 2 project created with [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/).
Here is my current dependencies object within `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
  "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",

  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
  "systemjs": "0.19.27",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.23",

  "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.1.13",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
},
```

When running `npm install` I get the following errors:

```
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.1.2 requires a peer of     @angular/compiler@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
```

I tried updating the dependencies based on the above warning, but ended up with a new list of similar warning and began to feel like I was "chasing my tail". Is there a straightforward way to add angular-in-memory-web-api to an Angular CLI created app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are just warnings (not errors). Npm peer dependency warnings are a natural occurrence. The majority of the time, this will not hinder your ability to use the module. I use CLI *and* the `angular-in-memory-web-api`. Just adding the following (which you have) is enough to make it all work (using the default Angular versions provided by the CLI).

```
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.1.13",
                       // version should be exact
                       // open regression issue with latest 0.1.14
```

If you've been changing around versions of everything, best thing to do is delete all the project `node_modules`, then reinstall everything.